# segmentation fault when trying to move pointer to next node Linked List?

Tags: linked-list, singly-linked-list

Hi i try to flatten a BST to Linked list. after store address of each node in a queue, i dequeue and form a doubly linked list. However i have segmentation fault when moving tailList pointer to next node. The code is below :

```
while(!Q.empty()){
        Node* newNode = Q.front();
        Q.pop();
        if(listRoot == NULL){
            listRoot = newNode;
            listRoot->left = NULL;
            listRoot->right = NULL;
            listTail = listRoot;
        }
        else{
            listTail->right = newNode;
            listTail = newNode;//segmentation fault
        }
    }
```

I initialise listRoot and listTail equal NULL at the start. And queue Q. I try to figure it out for hours now. Please help

Comment: probably add newNode->left = listTail and newNode->right = NULL, then move listTail = newNode

Comment: i tried several things like that and still segmentations fault

Comment: hey, nothing is wrong with the code. However I addedd newNode-> left = null and newNode->right=null. The error is the deconstructor when program terminates, I put delete entire tree function in the desconstructor, but its a linked list now . So error happens. Thanks

Comment: happy to know that the issue got resolved, though I highly doubt that my help was of any use :p